# Pandas extract substring from column of string using regex

Tags: regex, pandas, python-3.8

I have a dataframe with the string column as:

```
df['C23']

Col1 Col2
11   /*[lion]*/
21   /*[tiger]*/
```

I need the following:

```
Col1 Col2
11   lion
21   tiger
```

I tried the following code:

```
df['C23'].str.extract(r"/*(.*?)*/')
```

but it produces empty strings.

Comment: I am confused, is the column `C23` or `Col2`? is `11   /*[lion]*/` the content of the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['result'] = df['C23'].str.extract(r"/\*\[(.*?)]\*/")
```

The `/\*\[(.*?)]\*/` regex matches

- `/\*\[` - `/*[` string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `]\*/` - `]*/` string

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to convert `/*[lion]*/` to `lion` and all elements follow the same pattern, you do not need a regex, just slice:

```
df['Col2'] = df['Col2'].str[3:-3]
```